# Convert array into specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Given the following JSON

```
{
gif: ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
jpeg: ['tiny', 'huge']
}
```

I would like to convert each element in the array into a key in a sub object and assign it to it a quantity of 1.

As such

```
{
gif: {
  small: {quantity: 1},
  medium: {quantity: 1},
  large: {quantity:1}
  },
jpeg: {
  tiny: {quantity:1},
  huge: {quantity: 1}
  }
}
```

The closest I've come is with the following

```
for(let image in obj) { 
  obj[image].forEach(size => { obj[image][size] = { quantity:1}})
}
```

However unfortunately this out puts

```
{ gif: 
  [ 'small',
    'medium',
    'large',
     small: {quantity: 1},
     medium: {quantity: 1},
     large: {quantity: 1} ],
 jpeg: [ 'huge', 'tiny', tiny: {quantity:1} huge: {quantity: 1 } ] 
}
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.reduce()` method

```js
const obj = {
  gif: ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
  jpeg: ['tiny', 'huge']
};


for (let image in obj) {
  obj[image] = obj[image].reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item] = {
      quantity: 1
    };
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: While, all the other current solutions also work, and I'm aware the `for ...let` syntax  is the same as `Object.keys`,  this one one looks the simplest and easiest to read in IMHO. Thanks

Comment: @Verric `in` is NOT the same as `Object.keys()`. `in` has a very big caveat that you need to be aware of: that is that it includes properties from the prototype chain, which is normally not something you want when iterating over an object's properties.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it in-place using `reduce` within `forEach` loop:

```js
const o = {
  gif: ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
  jpeg: ['tiny', 'huge']
}

Object.keys(o)
  .forEach(
    k => o[k] = o[k].reduce(
      (a, e) => (a[e] = {
        quantity: 1
      }) && a, {}
    )
  )

console.log(o)
```

And convert into a new object using double `reduce`:

```js
const o = {
  gif: ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
  jpeg: ['tiny', 'huge']
}

var o2 = Object.keys(o).reduce((n, k) => (n[k] = o[k].reduce((a, e) => (a[e] = {quantity:1}) && a, {})) && n, {})

console.log(o2)
```

Comment: `&& a` seems nice. Is it safe? I would have done an `Object.assign()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method on `Object.keys` and inside you can use `map` and `Object.assign` to return new object.

```js
const data = {
  gif: ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
  jpeg: ['tiny', 'huge']
}

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e] = Object.assign({}, ...data[e].map(k => ({[k]: {quantity: 1}})))
  return r;
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
  gif: ['small', 'medium', 'large'],
  jpeg: ['tiny', 'huge']
}

const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);

for(let i=0;i<objKeys.length;i++){
  const currentKey = objKeys[i];
  obj[currentKey] = obj[currentKey].reduce((sum, element) => { 
    sum[element] = {quantity: 1};
    return sum;
  }, {});
}
```

This is one solution, you go through the array and replace it with objects